# Blazor Server App - OKTA Groups aren't appearing inside Claims

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, okta

I created a Blazor Server Web app in OKTA and enabled Open Id. Also added 2 users and their groups. Below is my code t configure OpenId inside Startup.cs. I am able to logged and getting Claim details.

```
//hk okta

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.Authority = Configuration["Okta:Domain"] + "/oauth2/default";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Okta:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Okta:ClientSecret"];
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "groups",
                    RequireSignedTokens = true
                };
            }
            );
```

Even though I am getting details inside Claim, Group names of logged users are not appearing anywhere. Is there any way to trouble shoot this or any other clue? I am looping through Claims like below.

```
@foreach (var claim in context.User.Claims)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@claim.Type</td>
                        <td>@claim.Value</td>
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that I wrongly selected a filter option inside Claims settings page, which made my groups wrongly filtered. Now all my groups are appearing inside Claim.

[image]

Comment: This looks correct, so I'm upvoting this answer. Here are the docs for creating a group claim in case anyone is looking. https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/customize-tokens-groups-claim/add-groups-claim-org-as/